# SharePoint Automation

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, infopath-rules

I've implemented InfoPath form (More than one view). and successfully published on SharePoint Document Library. i have some data actually which imported in SP from Excel. specific document recognise using unique column which is "Application ID".

If it is new "Application ID" which means ID is not exist in Document library after submitting form data save in Library using SPD workflow.

Till now all are working fine. but in final moment i stuck here- If user enter "Application ID" which already exist in document library. after submitting form how data (.xml File) updated without loosing old data (.xml file).

THanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you have 2 libraries and then SPD workflow saves the data from library A to B. In order not to overwrite your data You need to update your SPD workflow. Before saving form to new library query it if the Application ID exists there you need to append the the old entry (with suffix -old) before saving the new one.

Comment: I have only one Document Library. When item inserted workflow trigger. If App ID is not exist in library simply data is saving in library but when App ID is exist that time i want to Override the data (Old+New).